# Visual studio 2013 crash when mouse hovering over some things

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So whenever I just slide my mouse over all the application menu items (FILE, EDIT, VIEW etc.), not clicking anything, just hovering, VS hangs and never recovers. Also happens in some other places like the entries in performance explorer and some that I havent noticed exactly what it was.

It started when I first installed vs2013, I figured they might have fixed it in a service pack but no luck, now with latest updates still does that. What could it be? Never had that with the pervious versions.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and installing from scratch?

Comment: yes a couple of times